# Init a matrix in groovy

Tags: groovy

What's the easiest way to initialize a matrix?

```
// something like this would be nice
int[][] matrix = new int[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to define the variable type, use this:

```
int[][] matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

if the variable is untyped, use this:

```
def matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] as int[][]
```

Comment: Now I'm curious to how this works... that's some cool stuff (the ability to convert a List<List<Integer>> to int[][]).

Comment: it works by calling the `asType(Class type)` method that Groovy adds to `java.lang.Object` http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#asType(java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 1):

in groovysh I did

```
groovy:000> int[][]  matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]; println matrix[1][1]; println matrix.class
5
class [[I
===> null
```

note that there is a warning "Be careful: we don't support native multi-dimensional array creation right now."  found here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Migration+From+Classic+to+JSR+syntax

also, I put

```
 assert matrix instanceof int[][]
```

on the end and it seems to check out.

Comment: This creates a List<List<Integer>>, right? I guess it's somewhat equivalent to an int[][], although not quite.